# Forbidden things and tricks of OpenGL ES 1.x programming(Android)

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es

**This question is about OpenGL ES 1.x programming for Android.**

I followed [this tutorials](http://blog.jayway.com/2010/01/01/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-%E2%80%93-part-iii-%E2%80%93-transformations/) and tested code on Samsung Galaxy Ace and it lagged a bit.
Some code of that tutorial:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // Clears the screen and depth buffer.
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Replace the current matrix with the identity matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    // Translates 10 units into the screen.
    gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -10); 

    // SQUARE A
    // Save the current matrix.
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    // Rotate square A counter-clockwise.
    gl.glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);
    // Draw square A.
    square.draw(gl);
    // Restore the last matrix.
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    // SQUARE B
    // Save the current matrix
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    // Rotate square B before moving it, making it rotate around A.
    gl.glRotatef(-angle, 0, 0, 1);
    // Move square B.
    gl.glTranslatef(2, 0, 0);
    // Scale it to 50% of square A
    gl.glScalef(.5f, .5f, .5f);
    // Draw square B.
    square.draw(gl);            

    // SQUARE C
    // Save the current matrix
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    // Make the rotation around B
    gl.glRotatef(-angle, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.glTranslatef(2, 0, 0);
    // Scale it to 50% of square B
    gl.glScalef(.5f, .5f, .5f);
    // Rotate around it's own center.
    gl.glRotatef(angle*10, 0, 0, 1);
    // Draw square C.
    square.draw(gl);

    // Restore to the matrix as it was before C.
    gl.glPopMatrix();
    // Restore to the matrix as it was before B.
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    // Increse the angle.
    angle++;
}
```

- What are the week parts here?
- What should one do to optimize OpenGL ES program for Android?
- Should I rather use NDK in big graphics projects?
- Is it worth goind direct to OpenGL ES 2.0?

As far as I didn't find any good and complex book on OpenGL ES 1.x programming for Android, I adress this question to honorable users of Stackoverflow.
Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Note that openGL-es on android lags out in the emulator and in debug mode a lot more than when you just run it normally on a device

Answer (score 0):

Define lag? It might be helpful to look at framerate to get a better sense of performance.

But TBH, so long as `square.draw(gl)` is doing what it implies, then this is a very simple program. There is nothing performance heavy about this code.

I get the sense though that this is more of a speculative question for a bigger project. Some things to consider is what kind of graphical effects you will be trying to achieve. Will OpenGL ES 1.x be powerful enough for you? If you need to write custom shader code, you must use ES 2.0. Remember though, 2.0 requires you to write everything as a shader. It rips out many of the 1.0 features and gives those features to the developer to implement and customize. So development will be more complex and more time consuming.

As a warining, do not dive straight into the NDK as a starting point. All of these OpenGL calls are already native. It will be much (much much) easier to write an Android app in Java land than in C/C++ using JNI.

As a final word, early optimization is the root of all evil. Once you have selected your technologies, implemented a solution, and measured its performance, you can then worry about optimizing the code!